# Write live stream to response in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, http-streaming

I couldn't find an exact example of what I'm looking for.
I have a REST/WCF endpoint that takes in a `Stream` and returns a `Stream`. I am able to do "live" streaming of the request, by that I mean that the incoming stream gets read by the service as it is written to by the client (using a shared buffer stream in the service).

I would like to achieve the same thing on the outgoing stream but all the examples I found write all the data to a local stream **then** return it back to the client.

How can I access the underlying stream of the response and start writing to it, allowing the client to start reading from it without exiting my service method?
Is it even possible to achieve what I need with WCF and HTTP streaming?